# Getter method returns null for some things and the proper results for the other

Tags: java, json, gson

I have created a method to parse data from a JSON URL.

The data is put into a list and I want to show it in tabular form which I can.

I have getter and setter methods to get/set the information but when I use the get method for the Timestamp and deviceId, it returns a value. But when I use the get method for the measurment and measuring, it returns null/0.

Here is the JSON URL I am parsing from;

```
{
"status": "success",
"records": [
    {
        "timestamp": 1381735967866,
        "deviceId": "288",
        "temperature": 3304500
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1381735997866,
        "deviceId": "288",
        "temperature": 3304500
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1381736027866,
        "deviceId": "288",
        "temperature": 3304500
    }
```

That is only a snippet, but that is basically it.

Here is the java code used to divide the information;

```
public class Records 
{
private long timestamp;
private int deviceId;
private String measuring;
private int measurment;

public long getTimestamp() 
{ 
    return timestamp; 
}

public int getDeviceId() 
{ 
    return deviceId; 
}

public String getMeasuring()
{
    return measuring;
}

public int getMeasurment()
{
    return measurment;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) 
{ 
    this.timestamp = timestamp; 
}

public void setDeviceId(int deviceId) 
{ 
    this.deviceId = deviceId; 
}

public void setMeasuring(String measuring)
{
    this.measuring = measuring;
}

public void setMeasurment(int measurment)
{
    this.measurment = measurment;
}

public String toString()
{
    return String.format("Timestamp: %d\tDevice ID: %d\t%s: %d", timestamp, deviceId, measuring, measurment);
}
}
```

I call the String measuring and not temperature as there is other JSON URL's I am also parsing and they have different values to temperature (load, displacement etc) but deviceId and Timestamp are the same.

Here is how I print up the results;

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Elements elements = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Elements.class);

long previousTimestamp = 01;
long result;

for(Records records : elements.getRecords())
{
    System.out.println(records + "\n");
}
```

The printed result is this;

Timestamp: 1381746686550    Device ID: 288  null: 0

Timestamp: 1381746716550    Device ID: 288  null: 0

Timestamp: 1381746746550    Device ID: 288  null: 0

Timestamp: 1381746776550    Device ID: 288  null: 0

Timestamp: 1381746806550    Device ID: 288  null: 0

Timestamp: 1381746836550    Device ID: 288  null: 0

Timestamp and deviceId print out but measurment and measuring does not.

What I was hoping for when I call the temperature URL, temperature will be in place of null and an int value in place of 0. Same for displacement, load etc

Does anybody have any information or help, it would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        "timestamp": 1381736027866,
        "deviceId": "288",
        "temperature": 3304500
}
```

Your json does not have the data for `measuring` and `measurment`. And that is the reason, that you're not able to see them in the output. Since `measuring` is a String, you get a `null`(default value if a String is not initialized) when it was not populated and as `measurment` is an `int`, you get the default value of `0`.

If your json had those 2 elements, like this

```
{
        "timestamp": 1381736027866,
        "deviceId": "288",
        "temperature": 3304500,
        "measuring": "someMeasureValue",
        "measurment": 10
}
```

Then it would have populated those values in the object and the output would have been

```
Timestamp: 1381746686550 Device ID: 288 someMeasureValue: 10
```

Comment: temperature is the only value that changes (apart from the numbers that is), what would be the best way to go about writing code that will display the relevant info?
I thought I was onto a winner with that, but I had a feeling that thats what someone would answer

Comment: Can you show a sample of the possible changes your json can have?! Looking at this json, your `Records` class structure is a bit off.

Comment: `{
   "timestamp": 1381735967383,
   "load": 0,
   "deviceId": "286"
}`

The timestamp value always changes, deviceId not neccessarily but you can see here we are measuring load instead of temperature, that has different values

Comment: Also how is my Records class structure off a bit? I thought I had it all done OK.

Comment: Oh sorry, if this is the json. Then its pretty much okay. Just that, if your JSON won't contain the measurement and measuring fields in the json, it won't get populated at all and you're bound to get a null in that case.

Comment: so what your saying is if I wanted to print results for a JSON with displacement,load etc, I have to create a records class for each?

Comment: yes, you have to create a complete structure that maps 1-to-1 to your JSON